# 'interact_plot' not reflecting values in y-axis

Tags: r, plot, interaction-plot

I am looking at an interaction plot using 'interact_plot' function. Y variable ranges from 0 to 16 but the y-axis is only showing partial values. How do I edit the y-axis?

Below is my code and the plot:

```
all4.wsr.tnp1 <- lm(Total_number_of_preg ~ WSR_scale + Age + Age2 + nation + nation:WSR_scale, data = all4.sd.wsr.tnp)
interact_plot(all4.wsr.tnp1, pred=WSR_scale, modx=nation, interval=TRUE, int.width=.95, 
              johnson_neyman = FALSE, x.label = "WSR scaled", y.label="Total num of pregnancy",
              legend.main = "Nation")
```

Plot with limited y values:

[image]

BTW, 'Scale_y_continuous' or 'ylim' functions won't help.